# Local Area Network Discovery in Electron Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, electron, p2p

I am currently working on a local area messaging application using Electron, with the requirement that the application should function without access to the internet or any external servers. To achieve this, I am attempting to implement a solution where two instances of Node.js can discover each other on a local area network, allowing one of them to act as a signaling server for subsequent peer-to-peer communication.

I've tried utilizing both the mdns and bonjour libraries, but have encountered difficulties in achieving successful discovery. Below is a snippet of my current Electron main.js file and the corresponding server.js file:

```js
/// main.js
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const childProcess = require('child_process');

// Function to create the main window
function createWindow() {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        fullscreen: true,
        minWidth: 1024,
        minHeight: 720,
        frame: false,
        webPreferences: {
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: preloadPath,
        },
    });

    win.loadURL('http://localhost:3000');

    const serverProcess = childProcess.spawn('node', ['server.js'], {
        cwd: __dirname,
    });
    serverProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`Server output: ${data}`);
    });
    serverProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.error(`Server error: ${data}`);
    });
}

// Create the main window when the app is ready
app.whenReady().then(createWindow);

// Quit the app when all windows are closed
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});

// Recreate the main window when the app is activated
app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});


/// server.js
const bonjour = require('bonjour')();

// Advertise a service
const service = bonjour.publish({
    name: 'RiFFlo',
    type: 'http',
    port: 3000,
});

console.log('Service advertised:', service);

// Discover other services
const browser = bonjour.find({ type: 'http' });

browser.on('up', (service) => {
    console.log('Service up:', service);
});

browser.on('down', (service) => {
    console.log('Service down:', service);
});

browser.start();

// Handle process exit
process.on('exit', () => {
    service.stop();
    browser.stop();
    console.log('Exiting...');
});
```

I have not been able to successfully log other machines on the local network. Kindly provide some guidance or suggestions on how to implement a solution for local area network discovery in this context.